# How to create dynamic fixtures in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, fixtures

Say I have a calendar table that is supposed to keep track of cars entering a parking hall. `ParkingTime` is a domain class for that table.

I'd like to fill up my database with fixture data for last 30 days. Instead of hardcoding dates as strings and repeating object rows 30 times for each car these should be way to do this in a for loop.

Single entry for table:

```
include "Cars"

fixture {
    entry(ParkingTime, car: bmw123, arrival: arrivalDate.getTime(), departure: departureDate.getTime())
}
```

Ran in a loop like:

```
for (i in 1..30) {
    arrivalDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    departureDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    entry(ParkingTime, car: bmw123, arrival: arrivalDate.getTime(), departure: departureDate.getTime())
}
```

Where `arrivalDate` and `departureDate` are `Calendar` objects dated 30 days to the past.

My expectation was to run loop inside the `fixture{}` object and get 30 rows in a database. But there's only one row which is the last iteration from the loop.

Am I in a totally wrong track here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you are overriding the variable `entry`

Try instead

```
"entry$i"(ParkingTime,....)
```

Let me know

Comment: That does it! I forgot to add that I'm a novice to Grails and Groovy.